# How do I get Ubuntu in VirtualBox to give me a proper IP?

Tags: ip, virtualbox-networking

I recently set up a VirtualBox with Ubuntu in it in order to run a server for a game, which I need to access from my Windows on the same PC, where the game is kept. I have absolutely zero knowledge and no experience with anything like this, but I followed clear instructions on how to do this.

When it was all done, I found out that my internal and external Ubuntu IP was the same, even though they were supposed to be different. The person whose instructions I followed said that the IP (I think the internal one) should start with 10 or 192, which mine did not. One of them should also be the same as my regular Windows IP, which it wasn't either.

I used bridged adapter in the VB for the network, but after finding the IP problem I tried changing it to NAT, based on something I saw online. It fixed it and my IPs looked fine, but it made my server stop working. Supposedly I can only use bridged adapter for this project. I changed back to it, and the server is working again, but I'm still unable to connect to it. How can I get my IPs right with the bridged adapter setting so I can connect to my server?

I was supposed to pick the right network card in a list next to the bridged adapter, but only one is showing there (one with Ethernet Connection in the name, which doesn't even sound like a card to me, but I'm awful at that kind of stuff so maybe it's fine?).

I would be extremely grateful for any help, as making this work is a big dream of mine and I have put so much effort in and worked through so many problems and now I'm falling at the last hurdle.

People kept telling me to just reinstall Ubuntu and VirtualBox, so I finally gave in and threw all my hard work away to reinstall it. And I'm still getting the same useless IP. Do I have to find an exorcist for networks or how can I stop this evil force and get to have a proper IP that works?

As I mentioned above, I need the IP to reach a server on the Ubuntu which is for a game. When I try to connect to it through the game, I get these messages:

```
Connection failed
Cannot connect to a login server
Error: Disconnected from server"
```

I have tried pinging the IP, and it responds to that. But it appears that I need a proper IP like on my Windows, but I've only succeeded in getting it through switching away from the bridged adapter, which breaks the server. Other people have done the same process as me and it works for them and they don't get the weird IP I get.

Here's my ping. I got it from opening cmd.exe (in Windows) and typing `ping (the bad IP)`:

[image]

Please don't assume any knowledge on my part with your answers, and be very specific, otherwise I'll most likely just get confused and end up having more questions.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/148660/discussion-on-question-by-sret-how-do-i-get-ubuntu-in-virtualbox-to-give-me-a-pr); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: What's the IPs of your PC and your VM? And what's the VM's network settings? We don't see what you see so screenshots of these are useful. And if its a 192.168.x.x IP, its fine to share

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are fighting windmills. There are no bad IP addresses. The ones starting with 10. 172.16 to 31 and 192.168 are internal IP addresses, as in they don't route to the internet. Most internet connections I see use a little box that does the NAT'ing to translate the internal address to an actual routable address from your internet provider. Keeping it secret helps prevent unwanted traffic. The private addresses do not matter

With virtual machines you get a virtual network card to your host. From your story I think you want the VirtualBox to act as a second device in your network. Setup the net on VirtualBox to be external, this will setup a bridge between your hosts network and the internal. Then on the guest request an IP through DHCP from your little box.

Windows bridged networks are hard to setup. For me they do not always work and I recreate them.

I try to troubleshoot systematically what can I reach and what not one step at a time. And draw it out on paper. With that approach I can fix anything.

Comment: I vaguely recall it worked out of the box, but its been a while.